# Using file as input, iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, static-libraries

I have iPhone Library in c (it is created from c source in MAC). There is a method that read a file using file path. Now I want to input the file path in Objective-C to that method. My questions are:

- Is it possible to do? I mean use c library to read file on iPhone.

if it is possible,

- Where is the location in my project to put the file? (Resources ?)
- And, how can I get the path to be input in the method? (NSBundle ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really answer you first question, cause I don't know the answer.

But for the second file, the best location is the documents directory. 
To get the path of a file:

```
NSString* myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Or in a specific directory:

```
NSArray *myPathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *myDirectory = [myPathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPath = [myDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.plist"];
```

Hope that answered your question.

Regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use static C libraries on the iPhone, unless they have dependencies that cannot be resolved. Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can just code in C and use your library this way and it will compile just fine.